# Migrating application from RestEasy to Jersey

Tags: java, maven, jersey, cdi, resteasy

I am working on migrating an application from RestEasy implemenation to Jersey Implementation. The main problem I am facing is in the jars required for the CDI part.
While using resteasy, we are using the following 3 resteasy related jars

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-cdi</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.8-FINAL</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.8-FINAL</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-servlet-initializer</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.8-FINAL</version>
</dependency>
```

Now, to migrate it to Jersey, I am using the following jars in place of the resteasy jars.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-cdi1x-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
    <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Now when I try to deploy the EAR on the JBOSS server, I get the following error.

```
15:04:48,156 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-5) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.subunit."abc-ear.ear"."xyz-service-impl.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit."abc-ear.ear"."xyz-service-impl.war".POST_MODULE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of subdeployment "xyz-service-impl.war" of deployment "abc-ear.ear"
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:166) [jboss-as-server-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1980) [jboss-msc-1.1.5.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.5.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1913) [jboss-msc-1.1.5.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.5.Final-redhat-1]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS016053: Service class org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi1x.internal.CdiComponentProvider didn't implement the javax.enterprise.inject.spi.Extension interface
at org.jboss.as.weld.deployment.WeldPortableExtensions.tryRegisterExtension(WeldPortableExtensions.java:48)
at org.jboss.as.weld.deployment.processors.WeldPortableExtensionProcessor.loadAttachments(WeldPortableExtensionProcessor.java:119)
at org.jboss.as.weld.deployment.processors.WeldPortableExtensionProcessor.deploy(WeldPortableExtensionProcessor.java:79)
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:159) [jboss-as-server-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
... 5 more
```

As you can see from stack trace, the error that I am getting is `org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi1x.internal.CdiComponentProvider didn't implement the javax.enterprise.inject.spi.Extension interface`

I downloaded the source of the required jar to see if the class in question implements that interface or not. Well, it does implement the Extension interface.

Right now I am not able find a solution for this error.
I have tried various permutation and combination of different jersey jars but couldn't find a fix for this.
I have ran out of ideas. Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Recently I've done quite similar migration (RESTEasy 3.0.8.Final -> Jersey 2.23.1), but my migration also included the abandonment of the WildFly server. So it's quite big difference.

You haven't included any information about used Weld version, so please do it as this is very important here.

Anyway, two tips from my side before you'll update your question:

- There is a big chance that your error is caused by the EAR deployment. Because CDI and EAR archives sometimes don't play well together. Can you check what happen if you change your packaging to *.war?
- If you don't have a *very, very* good reason to migrate to a non-built-in JAX-RS implementation when still using Java EE app server and CDI, please don't do it. It's a tough task.

Ps. JFYI amount of problems with Weld and App servers which I've encountered pushed me to abandon them wherever I can.

**UPDATE**

You said you are using `Weld 1.1.23.FINAL` - this is very important information. Jersey + Weld integration changed heavily since Jersey 2.15. Personally, I wasn't able to make it work without some newer Weld version (2.3.5 in my case) - probably because this combination isn't supported.
In your case, as you're using extremely old Weld version, I would advice you to try at most Jersey 2.14.

In Jersey 2.14, needed dependencies were different. Please remove `jersey-cdi1x-servlet` and try this instead:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers.glassfish</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-gf-cdi</artifactId>
  <version>2.14</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers.glassfish</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-gf-cdi-ban-custom-hk2-binding</artifactId>
  <version>2.14</version>
</dependency>

<!-- is it needed for you?
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jboss.weld.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>weld-servlet-core</artifactId>
</dependency>
-->
```

BTW: may I know why you are changing JAX-RS implementation inside JBoss?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am using JBOSS EAP 6.3. So the WELD version that it uses is 1.1.23.FINAL. I got this information from this [link](https://access.redhat.com/articles/112673#EAP_6). Also I can't deploy it as a standalone war. My project has a bunch of wars. One of which is this WAR which is giving me the problem. This WAR uses the JBOSS deployment structure present in the EAR module.

Comment: I tried with the new set of jars that you suggested but I am still getting the same error.

Comment: The same error? It's **impossible** because the line: `JBAS016053: Service class org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi1x.internal.CdiComponentProvider didn't implement (...)` is a strong proof that you're still using `jersey-cdi1x.jar`. Please double check your dependencies.

Comment: I tripple checked the dependencies. But I am still getting the same error. JFYI, `org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi1x.internal.CdiComponentProvider` is also present in `jersey-gf-cdi-2.14.jar`.

Comment: Nope, almost but not the same. The former version has `org.glassfish.jersey.gf.cdi.internal.CdiComponentProvider` (notice lack of **ext.cdi1x**)... Anyway, if this won't work, you can either: abandon Jersey & CDI integration module and use the original HK2 binding and wire it "by hand" with your CDI beans, or stay with the RESTEasy. I don't see other options.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs buddy. I appreciate that.

Answer (score 0):

I have migrated to latest versions last month and this works for me.
try this.

```
<properties>
    <version.jersey>2.23.2</version.jersey>
    <version.glassfish>2.4.0</version.glassfish>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2.external</groupId>
        <artifactId>asm-all-repackaged</artifactId>
        <version>${version.glassfish}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <artifactId>hk2-utils</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2</groupId>
        <version>${version.glassfish}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
                <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.12</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
        <version>${version.jersey}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2</groupId>
                <artifactId>osgi-resource-locator</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2.external</groupId>
                <artifactId>aopalliance-repackaged</artifactId>
            </exclusion>                            
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>${version.jersey}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
        <version>${version.jersey}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: But you are not using a CDI, but HK2 injection framework. And it makes a huge difference.

Comment: Thanks pal, but still my answer may not solve anything :) It's rather a clue.

Answer (score -1):

You might be using wrong dependancies. Check this:
https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/modules-and-dependencies.html

Comment: This is just a vague answer. That page has a bunch of so many dependencies. Moreover I have used dependencies listed on that page which I thought were most logical. I am looking for something precise as against what you have mentioned.